# How to make mobile internet super slow?

Tags: android, mobile-data

I need to make my android phone's internet really really slow at midnight. Slow like 2G. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

follow 4 step
fist step open your setting mobile or emulator
[image]

second step click on network and internet

[image]

third step: click on mobile network
[image]

fourth step: click on preferred network and choice your preferred network type
[image]

names maybe have changed on your mobile phone
2G / GSM
3G / WCDMA/GSM
4G (recommended) / LTE/WCDMA/GSM

Answer (score 0):

Amir's answer is correct if you want to do it manually. For programmatic approach, this answer is available
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607289/4491971

Also this answer for rooted device.
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93128/237429

There is this app that you may also be interested to look at.
https://qr.ae/pGok3J